# Incrementing variable used as array index in function call

Tags: c, arrays, gcc

in C this works as I expect

```
void foo(int a, int b ) { printf("%i,%i ",a,b ); }

int main()
{
  int i=1;
  foo(i++,i);
  foo(i++,i);
  foo(i++,i);
  foo(i++,i);
  return(0);
}
```

output: 1,2 2,3 3,4 4,5

Now, the following does not work as I would have guessed:
    void foo(int a, int b ) { printf("%i,%i ",a,b ); }

```
int main()
{
  int a[] = { 100,200,300,400,500,600,700 };
  int i=0;
  foo(a[i++],a[i]);
  foo(a[i++],a[i]);
  foo(a[i++],a[i]);
  foo(a[i++],a[i]);
  return(0);
}
```

It returns
100,100 200,200 300,300 400,400

Following the logic of the previous example, I would have expected
100,200 200,300 300,400 400,500

My first suspicion was that the increment was only called after the function call, however, as the first example shows, i is indeed incremented inside the function call, unless it is used as an index for the array.

I also tried the same using  foo(*(a+(sizeof(int)*i++)),*(a+(sizeof(int)*i))); just to check, and it also acts like the second example.

The compiler is gcc version 4.6.3

My question is, why does it work when I'm using the variable i directly as the function parameter, but not when I use the variable i as an index for an array which is used as the function parameter?

Comment: not only this is a duplicate, but also the question arises, why do people want to write such crufty code? what is so bad in doing `foo(a[i], a[i+1]); i++;` ?

Comment: @JensGustedt: They write such code because they have a different mental model of how C works. In their model, arguments are completely evaluated in the order they are written, and `foo(i++, i)` is completely defined. The actual C model violates two normal human habits: The order of evaluation is not the same order the text is read in, and the order of evaluation is not uniquely determined. Because these properties are unfamiliar to some learners, they must be taught. The latter property is also abstract and therefore harder to teach by example.

Comment: @JensGustedt for( i= 0; i < 8; i+=2) someFunction(array[i++], array[i] ); - That's why, I know I can just do someFunction( array[i], array[i+1] ); but that's way too readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of your code invokes [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You may get either expected or unexpected result.
Compile your code with `-Wall` flag. Compiler should give the warning:

```
[Warning] operation on 'i' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
```

Read the [C_FAQ - 3.8](http://www.c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html). It explains this issue pretty well.

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to forget that C is not perfect.